# Euterpea and fluidsynth on a Mac: yet more problems

Tags: terminal, midi

In a previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977864/installing-euterpea-for-computer-music-applications-and-haskell (which relates to this question [Euterpea and fluidsynth on a Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347836/euterpea-and-fluidsynth-on-a-mac) too), on installing Euterpea on a Mac via the terminal, I was advised to enter the command

`fluidsynth -s -a coreaudio -m coreaudio /usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2`

I was told that if I couldn't find the FluidR3_GM.sf2 file then it's likely it's been installed in a different location, and that, as a last resort, I could just download a soundfont file and use that rather than the one provided by FluidSynth.

When I search for the FluidR3_GM.sf2 file, I receive the following errors. What can I do? Also, how can I run the command above successfully?

```
 Mo-MacBook-Pro:app Mo$ sudo find / -name FluidR3_GM.sf2
 Password:
 find: /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/tw/v9nkymhj461_yh7bl98n90k80000gp/0/SafariFamily: 
 Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/tw/v9nkymhj461_yh7bl98n90k80000gp/0/com.apple.
 Safari/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/tw/v9nkymhj461_yh7bl98n90k80000gp/0/com.apple.
 LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/tw/v9nkymhj461_yh7bl98n90k80000gp/0/com.apple.
 nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/tw/v9nkymhj461_yh7bl98n90k80000gp/0/com.apple.
 routined: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/tw/v9nkymhj461_yh7bl98n90k80000gp/C/com.apple.
 QuickLook.thumbnailcache: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000sm00006d/0: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000sm00006d/C: Operation not permitted
 find:/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000y800007k/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
 find:/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000z000007r/0/com.apple.nsur. 
 lsessiond: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000z000007r/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/0/SafariFamily:Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/0/com.apple.Safari/Sa      
 fariFamily: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/C/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache: Operation not permitted
 find: /private/var/folders/8m/0brzdqzx4vs_r1lj2n2qnk7c0000gq/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
 find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
 find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
```

Comment: those errors are permission errors.  Run the command again, but this time prepend the command `sudo`.

Comment: `sudo` was in the command. Do you mean the command `sudo. –`?

Comment: So sorry...I don't know what I didn't see that!